# How to use single catch function for nested async await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, promise, async-await

I have this code:

```
on('connection', async(socket) => {
  try {
    const promises = members.map(async(member) => {
      try {
        const users = await User.find({})
        const _promises = users.map(async() => {
          try {
            //some code here
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
          }
        })
        await Promise.all(_promises)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    })
    await Promise.all(promises)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    throw err
  }
})
```

As you can see I have a `try` `catch` for each nested `async` function. Would it be possible to tweak the code to use only a single `catch`, or to simplify things somehow?

Comment: Did you try just... *not* having them nested? If you want a single catch, have a single try.

Comment: @jonrsharpe When I remove `catch` from nested async function then I do not get any error when I get error inside it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes Updated my question. pls check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have just a single `await` at the top level of the handler. If the Promises spawned inside it all chain together to a Promise which is `await`ed at the top level (like in your example), that top `await` will catch errors thrown anywhere inside.

But, your `catch` section should *not* `throw` another error unless `.on` handles Promise rejections as well, otherwise you'll get an unhandled Promise rejection:

```
on('connection', async(socket) => {
  try {
    const promises = members.map(async(member) => {
      const users = await User.find({})
      const _promises = users.map(async() => {
        //some code here which may throw
      });
      await Promise.all(_promises);
    });
    await Promise.all(promises);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})
```

- If `await User.find` throws, then the `promises` array will contain a Promise which rejects, which mean that the top `await Promise.all(promises);` will throw and be caught
- If something inside `users.map` throws, `_promises` will contain a Promise which rejects, so `await Promise.all(_promises);` will throw. But that's inside the `const promises = members.map` callback, so that will result in `promises` containing a rejected Promise too - so it will be caught by the `await Promise.all(promises);` as well.

Answer (score 2):

If a function you call throws an error, the error will fall back to the nearest catch block the function call is enclosed in.

```
try {

   throw "an error";

}
catch(e) {
   console.log(e);   //output: "an error"
}
```

Now consider this

```
try {

  try {

   throw "an error";

  }
  catch(e) {

    console.log(e);   //output: "an error"

  }

}
catch(e) {
   console.log(e);   //This line is not going to be executed
}
```

This mechanism enables attachment of more error information to the generated error in each level. Imagine your error is an object and each nested catch bock attaching its own information to the error object an pass it along by throwing again.

Look at the following code:

try {

```
  try {

   throw {internalError: 101};

  }
  catch(e) {

    //Attach more info and throw again 
    e.additionalInfo = 'Disconnected when gathering information';
    throw e;

  }

}
catch(e) {
   e.message = 'Cannot get information'
   console.log(e);   //Final error with lot of information
}
```